# how to install cygwin and mingw under windows 7?

Tags: gcc, windows-7, g++, cygwin, mingw

I want to use gcc ( and g++ ) under windows 7. 
I download cygwin ( setup file: setup.exe )...

So, what is packages really needed?! It suggests to setup very many packages, but i think that for developing in C++ not all of these is really needed..

Answer (score 7):

- `gcc4-g++` for Cygwin programs
- `mingw64-i686-gcc-g++` for 32-bit MinGW programs
- `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` for 64-bit MinGW programs

Setup.exe will select their dependencies such as gcc-core or binutils for you.

You'll probably also want `make`, and don't forget to pick an editor. Other packages in my minimum install: `cygutils`, `diffutils`, `util-linux`, `inetutils`, `openssh`, `mintty`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use only gcc and g++, I'd receomend you MinGW Distro designed by Stephan T. Lavavej.
Here is a direct link: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html to the Distro's main page. It contains currently the most up to date gcc and boost (4.7.2 and 1.52.0 respectively in version 9.5). It also contains make, git and couple more of useful tools.

Installation is really simple, you need only to extract zip-archive.

So, if you need Cygwin only to use GCC, I'd recomment you this MinGW Distro instead of Cygwin.

Greetings,